# Regex in matching exact word

Tags: regex

I am trying to match an exact word before last dot and after last dot it should be number.

```
(\W*((?i)rocket\.jhagsc\.djagsh(?-i)(.*(?=\.).))\W*)((.*(?=\.).)(\d+))
```

Example:

```
rocket.jhagsc.djagsh.465465
```

It should match.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `\b(?i)rocket\.jhagsc\.(djagsh(?-i)\.\d+)\b` https://regex101.com/r/AMoeAZ/1

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase this as:

```
\brocket.jhagsc.djagsh[^.]*\.(?!.*\.)\d.*$
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
\brocket.jhagsc.djagsh   match your exact word
[^.]*                    then match zero or more non dots (i.e. allow no dots)
\.                       match the final dot
(?!.*\.)                 then assert that no more dots occur in the string
\d                       match a single digit immediately after the final dot
.*                       consume the remainder of the string
$                        end of the string
```

### Demo